# How do I programmatically merge cases from datasets with conflicting variable names?

Tags: spss

I want to add cases from many SPSS dataset to one SPSS dataset.

Here's my code:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
ADD FILES /FILE=*
  /FILE='Path\to\dataset.sav'.
EXECUTE.
```

But I get this error: `Mismatched variable types on the input files`.

I want SPSS to ignore the conflicting columns and add cases only from the columns where there is no conflict.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs because variables of the same name in the two different data sources have either **different format types** (STRING, NUMERIC, DATE ect) or either they are **both STRINGS but of different length**.

The latter, string variables of different lenghts, can be solved like this:

```
DATA LIST FREE / V(A1).
BEGIN DATA.
a b c
END DATA.
DATASET NAME DS1.

DATA LIST FREE / V(A2).
BEGIN DATA.
1 2 3
END DATA.
DATASET NAME DS2.

STATS ADJUST WIDTHS VARIABLES=ALL WIDTH=MAX /FILES DS1 DS2.

DATASET ACTIVATE DS1.
ADD FILES FILE=* /FILE=DS2.
```

However, if you have mismatch of different format types then that is a tad more complicated to solve due to many different permutations, so you would probably want to asses which variables are problematic and harmonize/delete them before merging files. Probably worth carrying out this exercise  nonetheless as having same variable names with different format type could be signs of erroneous data.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which variables conflict, you can use the KEEP subcommand to select the others, or you can use the RENAME command to assign new names and adjust the results afterwards.

If you need to harmonize the names and the issue is something like differing string lengths for variables that should be the same, the STATS ADJUST WIDTHS extension command can harmonize the widths before you merge.